# If streamreader doesn't lock a file just to read it, why is the file locked until a dialogue box is clicked away?

Tags: c#

Plenty of information on `StreamReader` and not locking files on stackoverflow, but does a dialogue box somehow change that?  I'd have to say no, but maybe I am not using it right, and it is locking the file?  My code is:

```
private void read1()
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"T:\\testfile");
    string input = null;
    while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (input.Contains("test"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(input);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you not able to read the file with another process, or write?

Comment: Where exactly did you hear that streamreader doesn't lock a file?  I believe StreamReader opens the file in FileShare.Read mode, which allows shared reading, but not opening it for writing.

Comment: While the dialogue box is present, I try saving to the file with a text editor and it can't save, but once I close the dialogue box it frees up the file.

Comment: @MystereMan is correct.

Comment: Thanks MystereMan, that will work for me.  I was trying to test it, and wasn't thinking about dual reading/actually writing as being different things.

Comment: To my knowledge (which might be limited) there is no OS that will allow to open a file for read and not lock it for write meaning whenever you open a file for read - other processes will not be able to write in it. if you open it for write - other processes will not be able to read from it or write to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a FileStream to do that.

Also, you're not closing your stream or calling Dispose() on it. You should use a `using` statement to make sure it happens. The following code should ensure the file isn't locked.

```
private void read1()
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"T:\testfile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
        using (var tr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
            string input = null;
            while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (input.Contains("test"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(input);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Steve, not closing the stream was also a problem in my code.